# Table view cell reload first cell content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is how my table is populated :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CellNewsInfo *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {

        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    // Set up the cell
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    NSString *titleArticle=[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
  titleArticle = [titleArticle stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        scr=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
        scr.tag = 1;
        scr.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
        [cell addSubview:scr];
        [self setupScrollView:scr];
        UIPageControl *pgCtr = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 170, 80, 36)];
        [pgCtr setTag:12];
        pgCtr.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        pgCtr.numberOfPages=5;
        pgCtr.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
        pgCtr.pageIndicatorTintColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        self.pageControl.hidden=YES;
        pgCtr.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        pgCtr.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
        [cell addSubview:pgCtr];
    }
    else{
    cell.title.text=titleArticle;
    cell.title.numberOfLines=2;
```

why when i scroll it , the first cell is reloading ? i just want to have that scroll view only once at the beginig .

Comment: Add your code in if (!cell) and then try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your scrollview is being added again is that the cells are being reused once they are deallocated.

You should look into creating your own custom cells if you are going to display multiple cells types in one tableView, or even using two different cell identifiers depending on if the row is 0.

```
CellNewsInfo *cell;
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"scrollCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell viewWithTag:1]) {
        scr = [cell viewWithTag:1];
    }
    else {
        scr=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
        scr.tag = 1;
    }
    // continue customization here with scrollview
}
else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // continue customization here without scroll view
}

return cell;
```

Comment: your ideea is working , Thanks , but another thing is happening now . After i scroll and i came back to the top ,  the automatic scroll it doesnt work , It seems like there are 2 scroll views.

Comment: Before adding your scrollview to the cell, check and see if it is already there. Check if the cell contains the subview with the tag you're giving it, and if it does, continue with the assigning values, if it doesn't, create and add it before assign values to it.